# conceptual doubt on change in entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

we have learnt in thermo that delta S is zero in reversible process

Now, when a solid melts reversibly is delta s zero since reversible or positive since the particles are more energetic in liquid phase

which one do I follow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: delta S total is zero in reversible process. For solid melts reversibly, delta S of system increases and delta S of surrounding decreases by same amount, so delta S total is zero.

Comment: how can delta total be zero should it not  always increase?

Comment: Note that "more energetic", especially in the conte of the question, is a vague assertion as for energy might refer to different state functions. Besides, the comment above should answer.

Comment: @Alchimista yep ,but can delta total be zero?

Comment: delta zero total increase in spontaneous process; delta zero total = 0 during reversible process.

Comment: @JustJohan yes it can be zero if the process of reversible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a reversible process, the entropy change of system plus surroundings is zero.  But neither of them has to be zero individually, and one can be positive while the other is negative.

For an irreversible process, the entropy change of system plus surroundings must be positive.  But, here, one of them can be negative while the other is more positive.